# "Lateinit was never initialized" while it is actually initialized inside a ListenerForSingleValueEvent

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Updated code in Edit 2

**Edit:**
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802039/java-how-to-return-the-variable-outside-the-listener) which I think addresses the same issue but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what's happening here as it's in Java and my Java is not as good as my kotlin. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Whenever I declare a lateinit variable and then initialize it from a `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`, I get an error that it was never initialized. It's like the initialization is bounded by the listener. What I end up doing is a lot of nesting, but it makes the code very messy. Is there a reason for that? A way around it?

For example, in this following code I will get an error saying that `userProfile` was never initialized:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var userProfile: Users

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        arguments?.let {
            val safeArgs = ProfileFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)
            val userProfileUid = safeArgs.usersProfile
            val refUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$userProfileUid")

            refUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                }

                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    userProfile = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                }

            })
        }

        val uri = userProfile?.image
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profilePicture)
    profileName.text = userProfile?.name


    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

After reading Alex Mamo's answer on this Q and the one he attached, I have tried to change my code accordingly but still can't make it to work.

Here's y current code (the elements are different as I've been working on my code but it's exactly the same case)

*I've tried placing the cal for readData with the arguments section or after but neither work for me and I keep getting the error that imageObject wasn't initialized when I try to use it in the onViewCreated

```
class ImageFullSizeFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    lateinit var refImage: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var imageObject: Images

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        arguments?.let {
            val safeArgs = ImageFullSizeFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)

            val imageId = safeArgs.imageId

            refImage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/images/feed/$imageId")

            readData(object : MyImageCallBack {
                override fun onCallback(value: Images) {
                    imageObject = value
                }
            })
        }
    }



    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val mainImage = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_full_image)

        Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(imageObject.image)).into(mainImage)
    }


    fun readData(myImagesCallback: MyImageCallBack) {


        refImage.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                val image = p0.getValue(Images::class.java)

                myImagesCallback.onCallback(image!!)

            }


        })

    }
}
```

And this is the interface:

```
interface MyImageCallBack {
    fun onCallback(value: Images)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onDataChange()` function returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `userProfile` object that you are getting from the database and you're trying to use it outside the callback, will not have been populated yet.

Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended. So, in this case it has nothing to do with the `lateinit`.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the following lines of code:

```
val uri = userProfile?.image
Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profilePicture)
profileName.text = userProfile?.name
```

And use them **only** inside the callback. In this way the data that it comes from the database will be available.

If you want to use it outside tha callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. It's for Cloud Firestore but same rules apply in case of Firebase realtime database.

Comment: Thanks Alex and sorry for the late reply. I feel like I have to use it outside the call back, because my fragment is hosting another fragment, and that child fragment needs to have access to that object I am getting from the listener. I have looked at your other answer and it seems clean and straight forward but I must be missing something because I can't get it to work. Mind telling me what it is I am getting wrong? I've added an edit with my new code (the elements are different as I've been working on my code but it's exactly the same case).

Comment: As I see, you are doing the same thing as before. Assigning `imageObject = value`  inside the `readData` function doesn't mean it will be able to simply use the value of `imageObject` in this line `Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(imageObject.image)).into(mainImage)`. To solve this, move that line inside `readData` function or change the logic of getting the data. This is how asynchronous programming works.

Comment: Sorry for the late replies I'm from Australia haha. I've marked it as correct because It sounds right, but I personally ended up using Shared view models to transfer the data. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `val uri = userProfile?.image` **run** before `userProfile = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)` that why this problem happened.

Something I think it help

- `code2` below `code1` not mean it `code2` run after `code1` in **runtime**.
- "Lateinit was never initialized" is **runtime error** happened when you try to use a variable when it is not initialized in runtime **not** compile time.
- `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is `asynonymous`

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that if it comes after it then it will run after it. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, in this following code I will get an error saying that userProfile was never initialized.

#### Problem

When `onDataChange` is called, `userProfile` initialized. But before that you access `userProfile`. Therefore, a not initialized exception occurred.

#### Solution

move `setupViews` to `onDataChange`, try this code

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    userProfile = p0.getValue(Users::class.java).also {
        Picasso.get().load(it.image).into(profilePicture)
        profileName.text = it.name
    }
}
```